# Reifying the function implementation instead of the reference

Tags: scala, reflection, macros, scala-2.10

I need to get the AST of the implementation of a lambda function. And I get stuck because reify works on the argument and not on it's value.

```
val x = (a: Int) => println("a")
val t = showRaw(reify(thevalueof x)) //something here should change
println(t)
```

should print:

```
Expr(Function(List(ValDef(Modifiers(PARAM), newTermName("a"), Ident(scala.Int), EmptyTree)), Apply(Select(Select(This(newTypeName("scala")), newTermName("Predef")), newTermName("println")), List(Literal(Constant("a"))))))
```

I supposed there should be a trick with splice or so, but I just can't manage to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there is no robust way of getting ASTs of the program outside of a macro application (and reify is a macro, so it abides by the same rules). However, we are experimenting with a next-gen macro engine that might fix this problem: http://scalamacros.org/news/2014/03/02/project-palladium.html.